# Access underlying jsonl file of AzureML TabularDataset

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a `TabularDataset` containing labels that has been exported from a `Data Labeling` project.

I'd like to access the dataset through my `PythonScriptStep` as a `FileDataset` so I can access the underlying `jsonl` file directly.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be like so:

```py
from azureml.core import Workspace, Datastore, Dataset


workspace = Workspace.from_config()

def to_file_dataset(tabular_dataset):
    step_arguments = tabular_dataset._dataflow._get_steps()[0].arguments
    datastore_paths = [
        (Datastore(workspace, store["datastoreName"]), store["path"])
        for store in step_arguments["datastores"]
    ]
    return Dataset.File.from_files(path=datastore_paths)


labels = Dataset.get_by_name(workspace, name="labels_20211213_192446")


step_training = PythonScriptStep(
    script_name="training.py",
    source_directory="./src/training",
    arguments=[
        "--input-azureml-labels-dir",
        to_file_dataset(labels).as_mount(),
        "--input-ir-images-dir",
        selected_ir_images_dataset.as_mount(),
    ],
    runconfig=aml_run_config,
)
```

Then in the step script `training.py`, the `jsonl` file can be accessed.

```py
labels_pathlist = Path(args.input_azureml_labels_dir).glob("*.jsonl")
```